# Subsonic 3 - What is the difference between these approaches?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

This method works fine:

```
Person p = new Person(3);
p.Name = "Bob";
p.Update();
```

However if I have an IQueryable foreign key collection the below fails

```
var foreignItems = Person.Find(x => x.ID == 3)
foreach(Person p in foreignItems)
{
  p.Name = "Bob";
  p.Update(); /*THROWS EXCEPTION */
}
```

Exception is thrown in Repository Update as it executes a query from BuildUpdateQuery such as - UPDATE PERSON WHERE ID = {0} which is wrong syntax!

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how frequently people don't post the exception.

Comment: Obviously it's a sqlexception and he gives an example message.  Seems like a bug in ss3, you should report it.

Comment: Not sure where you report the bug to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug, you should report it to [github](http://github.com/subsonic) (the new host for SubSonic source).
In the meantime does calling p.Save() may work around the issue.

Comment: p.Save() calls Update() in ActiveRecord

Comment: So do you get the same exception when calling save?

Comment: No because it does an Add which is wrong.  It seems if in that loop you then say var item = new Person(p.ID); item.Save it all works but you shouldnt have to create a new instance of the object if you have a list of them instantiated by the Find method